# MathError in loop

Tags: java, logic

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DieClass
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times do you want to roll?");
        int rollamt = reader.nextInt();
        int arraySum [] = new int [13];

        for (int i = 0; i < rollamt; i++)
        {
            int [] arrayDice = new int [rollamt];
            int dice1 = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int dice2 = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int total = dice1 + dice2;
            arrayDice[i] = total;
            arraySum[total]++;

        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 13; x++)
        {
            double percent = arraySum[x] / rollamt * 100;
            System.out.println("Number " + x + " was rolled " 
            + arraySum[x] + " times. Percentage is " + percent + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is a logic error here. When I run it the percentage is always 0%. why is that? (int percent specifically)

By obtaining the value in my arraySum array I simple divide it by the amount of rolls and multiply it by 100.

Comment: change 100 to 100.0 and do arraySum[x] * 100.0 / rollamt

Comment: yeah i forgot about the order of operations, my bad @shmosel